# How I can use CUDA ConvNet in MATLAB, when its output is an image instead class label?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to train a Convolutional Neural Network based system in MATLAB with ConvNet toolbox. I want to get a restored image as its output. As I got from studying the ConvNet's page, its output should be the class label of an input image.
What should I do to train my system?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.  Why would the output be an image?  If you want to do some sort of image reconstruction, you'd have to assign a class label on a per pixel basis perhaps.  It doesn't make sense to assign an image at the output layer.

Comment: @rayryeng  How I can assign a class label per pixel for reconstruction? for example, It is 32*32 image as the input of CNN based system. How I can compare the output of convolutional layer with the ground truth (in the mean squared sense) to learn the parameters?

Comment: That requires a lot of training data that you probably don't have access to.  Image restoration in a machine learning perspective is usually done unsupervised.  Try using an autoencoder: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.08921.pdf

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you so much. However, I did not find the solution there!

Comment: Don't know. Sorry.